VS output window shows "The system cannot find the file specified" but compilig succeeds
I have a .NET core app compiling just fine but the output window keeps showing

"The system cannot find the file specified"

I went through app property editor as well as manually through appname.csproj with a text editor removing anything not strictly necessary but I seem unable to find the source of this messages.
Is there any way to actually see the commands or directives causing this?
Forms and WPF are enabled for this project. It happens in any build configuration ("Release" and "Debug").


Might be worth to check more verbose build logs

Have you tried a clean build? (Close Visual Studio and delete all temp folders and files, i.e. bin, obj, .vs folders,  .user file)

@Renat: this is exactly what I was looking for. Can you post it as an answer so I can mark it as solved?

Visual Studio and MSBuild can produce verbose logs for more info about what was happening during the build, as per Visual Studio docs:

... configure the logger verbosity with the following steps:

In Visual Studio, select Tools > Options to open the Options dialog.
On the dialog, expand the Projects and Solutions section and select the Build and Run tab.
Use the MSBuild project build output verbosity dropdown list and select your build output preference.
Use the MSBuild project build log file verbosity dropdown list and select your logger verbosity preference.


